# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitXenoCommon":

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, google-mlkit

I used the body detection plugin (body_detection: ^0.0.3) for ML task
When I try to install the pod I face an error. Screenshot of log attached

[image]

Firebase plugin version I'm using

```
  #Pose detection
  body_detection: ^0.0.3

  
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.0

  #FIREBASE
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
  firebase_core: ^2.9.0 
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.0 
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.2.1
```

Xcode version: 14.3

Flutter Version

```
Flutter 3.7.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4b12645012 (7 weeks ago) • 2023-04-03 17:46:48 -0700
Engine • revision ec975089ac
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1
```